# How to make a tableView with different detail view for each cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview, tablecell

I’m wrote the:

```
    func initializeMyDictionary() {
            self.example = [MyDictionary(name: "Some Name", text: "some text", link: "linkToSomeDocument"),
MyDictionary(name: "Second Name", text: "some text", link: "secondLink")]
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier: String = "tableCell"

        var cell: TableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? TableCell

        if cell == nil {

            cell = TableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        }

        cell!.nameLabel!.text = example[indexPath.row].name

        return cell!

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return example.count
    }
```

Then link it to DetailViewController (which I create) on Main.storyboard. And DetailView of every myDictionary String is shown in my tableView. All works fine.

But I want to make some row's show me second value from MyDictionary (link).
1 row show me "name" and "text" from MyDictionary, 2 row show me the document or URL from "link". Are it's impossible OR how to do something like that?

I'm sorry for ignorance and bad english.

Comment: try using `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` instead of `UITableViewCellStyle.Value1` and access name label through `cell!.textLabel!.text = example[indexPath.row].name` and subtitle label like `cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = example[indexPath.row].link` hope that's what you want

Comment: @anneblue thanks for answer, but I want to open different DetailView from cells for using different content into this cells.

For example: #1, #2, #3, #4 and #6 cell's open DetailViewController which I create (and this working for me without any problems); cell #5 I want to open RTF document, which I bind to it. BUT my problem is the following: Every cell open DetailViewController, and I can't make one of the cells some individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods:

**1.**

Remove the storyboard segue going from your prototype cell to the view controller and just implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `-(void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath` method and push another view controller there, like:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath 
{
    // the identifier of the viewController in storyboard
    NSString* identifier = nil;
    // section 0
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: 
            // rows in section 0
            switch (indexPath.row) { 
                // row 0 in section 0
                case 0: identifier = @"IdentifierOfVCForFirstCellInFirstSection"; break;
                case 1: identifier = @"IdentifierOfVCForSecondCellInFirstSection"; break;
                default: break;
            } 
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    // 
    if (identifier != nil) {
        // perform Segue programmatically 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: identifier] animated: YES];
    }
    else {
        NSAssert(NO, @"No storyboard identifier implemented for row %@ in section %@", @(indexPath.row), @(indexPath.section));
    }
}
```

---

**OR 2.**

Add (drag and drop) another prototype cell into your tableView in IB. Give it a different Reuse Identifier in Attributes Inspector.
Then connect it with your different wanted viewController (right-click and under `'Triggered Segues'` drag the `selection` to your desired view controller.

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method decide which kind of `UITableViewCell` you wand to dequeue dependent on your indexPath.

For this second solution I'd recommend to use custom UITableView subclass/Xib for the prototype cells.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Swift and Objective-C for me too hard. I will try your second solution after understand how to do this. Or can you by yourself edit the cellForRowAtIndexPath as you say Or more explain that. I'm so sorrry, and thank you for help.

Comment: Why initialize both VCs if only one is going to be used?

Comment: @ZaneHelton you're totally right, changed answer accordingly.